# How to typeset this cup product using tikz

Tags: positioning, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Can someone suggest how to typset this [image: cup product]

commutative diagram using tikz-cd. I'm unable to do it, instead I'm getting this [image: bad cup product].

This is what I have tried:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  H^p(G,A^{''}) \dar{\delta}  \times H^q(G,B) \dar{1} 
  \rar{\smile} & H^{p+q}(G,A^{''}\otimes B) \dar{\delta} \\
   H^{p+1}(G,A)  \times H^q(G,B) \rar{\smile} & H^{p+q+1}(G, 
   A\otimes B)
 \end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried

Comment: I have edited it now, with my attempt.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/174620). Please post a compilable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I prefer the `\arrow[]` notation for this. You can add `xshift=` to each arrow. Unrelated: Do you really want `\smile` instead of `\cup` for the cup product?

```
\begin{tikzcd}
   H^p(G,A^{''}) \times H^q(G,B) \arrow[d, "\delta"', xshift=-8mm]\arrow[d, "1"', xshift=11mm]  
   \rar{\smile} & H^{p+q}(G,A^{''}\otimes B) \dar{\delta} \\
   H^{p+1}(G,A)  \times H^q(G,B) \rar{\smile} & H^{p+q+1}(G, 
   A\otimes B)
\end{tikzcd}
```

Note the extra single quote `'` to place the arrow label on the left side.

Comment: I thought that $\smile$ is the most used notation these days for cup product. Hence, I thought I will use it too. I'm not really particular about it, given that the book I'm using (Neukirch's Bonn Lectures on Class Field Theory) sticks to $\cup$.

Comment: @S.SundaraNarasimhan: Yes, I like `\smile` better also; I just noticed the image you posted used `\cup`.